# Adding a view as subview to my app's window but it is not displayed

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiwindow

I'm adding a view controller's view to my window in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` but the view does not become visible. I'm not sure what's wrong.

Here's my app delegate code:

```
@class ToolBar;
@class MainViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

{
    UIWindow *Window;
    //UIToolbar *toolbar; 
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MainViewController *mainViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ToolBar *toolbar;

@end
```

---

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "ToolBar.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize mainViewController = _mainViewController;
@synthesize toolbar =toolbar;


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]autorelease];
    self.mainViewController = [[[MainViewController alloc]init]autorelease];
    [self.window addSubview:self.mainViewController.view];
    //[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    self.toolbar = [[[ToolBar alloc]init]autorelease];
    [self.window addSubview:toolbar.view];    
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, to start with you're not setting the frame for your toolbar.

But why are you adding a toolbar to your app's main window? I would expect it to be a subview of your mainViewController's view.

Comment: i had it as the subview of the main controller but the problem i was having when my view controllers were flipping toolbar was also flipping. which i don't want that is why now i m adding toolbar as subview of the app delegate. Now I have separate view controller for uitoolbar and that is where i m adding as int with frame

Comment: Just to be clear - the app delegate is NOT a view, so you're not adding the toolbar as a subview of the app delegate - you're adding at as a subview of your app's main window. Either way, what you're doing is wrong. The toolbar should be a subview of a view controller's view.